# How to change Colum Width in automatically in Excel

Tags: excel

**Hey, Folks! I want to colum width automatically
in my excel sheet looks like this**

[image: in my excel sheet looks like this]

**and I want to change look like this**

[image: and I want to change look like this]

[image: auto fill]

**I save this but I close the excel and I open never change**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would advise saving the document as the Excel-macro one .xslm.
2. Next open Developer and select Visual Basic. If you don't have the one, customize your ribbon:
   https://wellsr.com/vba/excel/enable-developer-tab/
3. In the VBA Excel project find the sheet you are working on
4. Provide the VBA code like this:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 15

   End Sub
   ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth

Every time you open this sheet it should be as wide as you defined in the code.

[image]

Comment: Okay i understand I should save **.xslm** and then problem has solved! i try to save on **.csv**  I get it thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind, that:
.xslx extensions removed all the macros from your workbook when you close it
.csv removes all the formulas provided to your workbook

saving constantly in .csv  you will receive only pure calculation results.